# exception when showing form

Tags: vb.net, forms

When I run my program and select button8 i get:

> An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for
>   details.  The error is: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

My code is as simple as -

```
Private Sub Button8_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click
    frequency.Show()
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

The error is on the `frequency.Show()` but i don't know how to fix it as all it does is open another form. I have run a check for errors and exceptions but nothing shows until I run it.

**EDIT** - added `frequency.Load` code from comments.

```
Dim LineOfText
Dim aryTextFile() As String
Dim Line As String
Using SR As New IO.StreamReader("...\mainmenu.txt")
    Do While Not SR.EndOfStream
        '________________
        LineOfText = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("...\mainmenu.txt")
        aryTextFile = LineOfText.Split(",")
        For i = 0 To UBound(aryTextFile)
            'MsgBox(aryTextFile(i))
        Next i
        ' Read the file just created
        Line = SR.ReadLine
        TextBox1.Text = aryTextFile(0)
        TextBox2.Text = aryTextFile(1)
        TextBox3.Text = aryTextFile(2)
        TextBox4.Text = Today
        TextBox5.Text = aryTextFile(4)
    Loop
End Using
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Where/how is `frequency` declared and initialized?

Comment: In your `frequency` Form, you've got an error in either the Constructor or the Load() event...post some code.

Comment: in my frequency_load section is a simple stream reader to read text file to array and to populate date from the array. this error is occuring on form1.vb

Comment: Post that "simple" code please...

Comment: Dim LineOfText
        Dim aryTextFile() As String
        Dim Line As String

        Using SR As New IO.StreamReader("...\mainmenu.txt")
            Do While Not SR.EndOfStream
                '________________
                LineOfText = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("...\mainmenu.txt")
                aryTextFile = LineOfText.Split(",")
                For i = 0 To UBound(aryTextFile)

                    'MsgBox(aryTextFile(i))
                Next i
                ' Read the file just created

Comment: Line = SR.ReadLine
                TextBox1.Text = aryTextFile(0)
                TextBox2.Text = aryTextFile(1)
                TextBox3.Text = aryTextFile(2)
                TextBox4.Text = Today
                TextBox5.Text = aryTextFile(4)
            Loop
        End Using

Comment: ...that's a mess.  How many lines are supposed to be in the file?  I assume one?  It'd be very easy for that code to generate errors based on the line(s) returned from the file.

Comment: yes, just 1 line only. the text is serparated by commas. my level of coding extends to simple college (uk) programs so i appologise. i debugged it one minute. stopped debugging. debugged again and bam.. that error.

Comment: Can you please post the stack trace of the exception.  That will show where the exception is occurring.

Comment: Idle_Mind- no go. still an error with frequency.show

Comment: i cant post stack trace without using about 4 comments on here... the first 3 lines are-    at Accounts.My.MyProject.MyForms.Create__Instance__[T](T Instance) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 190
   at Accounts.My.MyProject.MyForms.get_frequency()
   at Accounts.Form1.Button8_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Accounts - Copy\Accounts - Copy\Accounts\Form1.vb:line 84

Comment: After a rebuild of the entire program it is now working for some unknown reason. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your Load() event instead:

```
Public Class frequency

    Private Sub frequency_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Try
            Dim Lines() As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("...\ MainMenu.txt")
            Dim aryTextFile() As String = Lines(0).Split(",")
            TextBox1.Text = aryTextFile(0)
            TextBox2.Text = aryTextFile(1)
            TextBox3.Text = aryTextFile(2)
            TextBox4.Text = Today
            TextBox5.Text = aryTextFile(4)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error Loading File")
        End Try
    End Sub

End Class
```